# Change the widget-product-categories order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to change the widget-product-categories order to custom one (not just asc, desc)??? There's filter woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args but I have no idea how to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using JavaScript (by JS Plugin), much more freedom and it works. The code below reorders the sidebar categories based on the menu entries (and menu entries I'm using code snippets with hooks to reorder).

```
  var menu_product_categories = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-object-product_cat");
  var sidebar_product_categories = document.getElementsByClassName("cat-item");
  for (var loop_menu = 0; loop_menu < menu_product_categories.length; loop_menu++) {
    if (menu_product_categories[loop_menu].parentElement.classList.contains('nav-dropdown')) {
      for (var sidebar_loop = 0; sidebar_loop < sidebar_product_categories.length; sidebar_loop++) {
        if (sidebar_product_categories[sidebar_loop].parentElement.classList.contains('product-categories')) {
          if (loop_menu === sidebar_loop) {
            sidebar_product_categories[loop_menu].innerHTML = menu_product_categories[loop_menu].innerHTML;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```